# What thread.join() do in multithreading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I am trying to understand the thread join in C / C++. And I get to know that

> std::thread::join() function makes the current thread wait until the thread identified by *this has finished executing.

But I can't understand why the positioning of the join function is important and why this two code works differently.

**code 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include<vector>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void func(int x)
{
  sleep(100);
  cout<<x<<endl;
}

int main() {
  
  vector<thread> a;

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    a.emplace_back(func,i);
  }

  for (auto &thr : a) {
      thr.join();
      cout<<"next"<<endl;
  }

  cout<<"finish"<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
01
3

next
9
7
45
6
8
2next


next
next
next
next
next
next
next
next
finish
```

**Code 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include<vector>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void func(int x)
{
  sleep(100);
  cout<<x<<endl;
}

int main() {
  
  vector<thread> a;

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    a.emplace_back(func,i);
    a.back().join();
    cout<<"next"<<endl;
  }

  cout<<"finish"<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
0
next
1
next
2
next
3
next
4
next
5
next
6
next
7
next
8
next
9
next
finish
```

At first I thought that in code 1 as I join the threads later maybe they executed and finished already, but increasing the sleep time giving same result. So, I am confused.

Comment: In your second code, you don't create a new thread until the previous thread has already finished executing, no matter how long that takes.

Comment: The first code creates 10 threads, all of which are able to execute concurrently, and they are interleaved randomly (along with the main thread).  Then the main runs a loop joining each of the threads in order, so it waits for the first then the second .... then the tenth thread to complete before printing 'next`.    The loop in the second code creates a thread, and joins it (i.e. waits for it to complete) .... ten times.

Answer (score 4):

In your first version of code, this block

```
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    a.emplace_back(func,i);
  }
```

Does 2 things, it creates a `std::thread` instance and launches the threads. Now these threads are allowed to run until the main thread calls `join()`on them as in the next piece of code,

```
  for (auto &thr : a) {
      thr.join();
      cout<<"next"<<endl;
  }
```

So you,

1. Create all threads
2. Let all of them run
3. Call `join()` on them one by one.

In your Version 2, you again create the thread but then immediately call `join()` on the last inserted thread via `back()` i.e. the thread just created.

```
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    a.emplace_back(func,i);
    a.back().join();
    cout<<"next"<<endl;
  }
```

Thus each of the threads is launched, runs to its completion, and is then called `join()` upon. You essentially *serialize* the threads, hence the output. So here you,

1. Create a single thread
2. Allow it to run
3. Call `join()` on it.
4. Repeat this for all threads.

Answer (score 2):

In the first snippet, you start all the threads, then wait for all of them. In the second snippet, you wait for a thread to complete right after you start it, before moving on to the next one, so only one is running at a time.